# Why is my JavaScript Promises using the RSVP.js library returning an error after all my Promises succeeded?

Tags: javascript, promise, rsvp.js

The simple demo JavaScript code below uses the RSVP.js Promise Library https://github.com/tildeio/rsvp.js/ to load some JSON data using AJAX and on completion fires off some code after all JSON data has loaded.

After that it runs a non ajax function in a chained `then()` call

All my Promises are successful however it returns an error at the end as well!

I am not sure why the error is ran?

JSFiddle Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/jasondavis/fttzoggj/3/

```
var jsonPromiseCache = {};



// AJAX function to load JSON data using Promise()
var getJsonDataPromise = function(url, key) {

  if (!jsonPromiseCache[key]) {
     jsonPromiseCache[key] = new RSVP.Promise(function(resolve, reject){
      // If jsonPromiseCached data is not set then make AJAX requiest to get it


        var client = new XMLHttpRequest();
        client.open("GET", url);
        client.onreadystatechange = handler;
        client.responseType = "json";
        client.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        client.send();

        console.log('---- "client" XMLHttpRequest/AJAX  variable ======= ',client);


        function handler() {
          if (this.readyState === this.DONE) {
            // On AJAX success, resolve() our Promise() and set result to cached variable
            // to avoid duplicate AJAX requests for this jsonCache[key] Data where "key"
            // is used to assign to each AJAX endpoint URL/request of JSON data...
            // (milestones, tasks, users, etc...)
            if (this.status === 200) {
                jsonPromiseCache[key] = this.response;

                console.log('---- jsonPromiseCache['+key+'] ====== ',jsonPromiseCache[key]);

                // Resolve() the Promise() on AJAX success
                resolve(this.response);

            // On AJAX failure, reject() our Promise()
            }else{
                reject(this);
            }
          }
        };

      // If JSON data for this key is already jsonPromiseCached, then return the jsonPromiseCached version
      // instead of making a new AJAX request!
    });
  }
  return jsonPromiseCache[key];
};
```

**New non-ajax promise**

```
// testing a  non ajax Promise
function initDomEvents() {
    var eventsLoaded = true;

    //if (eventsLoaded) {
        jsonPromiseCache['domevents'] = eventsLoaded;

        console.log('---- initDomEvents() ran');

        // Resolve() the Promise() 
        //resolve(jsonPromiseCache['domevents']);
        resolve();

        // On false, reject() our Promise()
    //}else{
    //    reject();
    //}

};
```

**EXAMPLE USAGE DEMO**

```
// usage loading JSON data with AJAX using Promises
var promises = {
    users: getJsonDataPromise('/echo/json/', 'users'),
    task: getJsonDataPromise('/echo/json/', 'task')
};


RSVP.hash(promises)
.then(function(results) {
  console.log('then() function ran on success of loading JSON data');
  console.log(results);
  console.log('results.users', results.users); // print the users JSON results
  console.log('results.task', results.task); // print the task JSON results
})
.then(initDomEvents)
.finally(function(){
  console.log('finally() function ran on success and failure.... It is always ran!');
})
.catch(function(reason){
  console.log('[ERROR] REASON:',reason.statusText); //if any of the promises fails.
});
```

---

**UPDATE**

This new demo http://jsfiddle.net/jasondavis/fttzoggj/6/ adds a 3rd Promise and the 3rd one does not get ran!  THe 2nd Promise function `initDOmEvents()` returns this error now...

```
ERROR] REASON: ReferenceError: resolve is not defined
    at initDomEvents (http://fiddle.jshell.net/_display/:91:9)
    at G (http://apollowebstudio.com/labs/js/sugarcrm-pm/js/rsvp.min.js:2:6009)
    at F (http://apollowebstudio.com/labs/js/sugarcrm-pm/js/rsvp.min.js:2:5928)
    at L (http://apollowebstudio.com/labs/js/sugarcrm-pm/js/rsvp.min.js:2:6661)
    at MutationObserver.h (http://apollowebstudio.com/labs/js/sugarcrm-pm/js/rsvp.min.js:2:1667)
```

New code added...

// testing a  non ajax Promise

```
function initTaskModalLibraries() {
    var taskModalScriptsLoaded = true;

    if (taskModalScriptsLoaded) {
        jsonPromiseCache['inittaskmodallibraries'] = taskModalScriptsLoaded;

        console.log('---- initTaskModalLibraries() ran');

        // Resolve() the Promise() 
        //resolve(jsonPromiseCache['domevents']);
        resolve();

        // On false, reject() our Promise()
    }else{
        reject();
    }

};

RSVP.hash(promises)
.then(function(results) {
  console.log('then() function ran on success of loading JSON data');
  console.log(results);
  console.log('results.users', results.users); // print the users JSON results
  console.log('results.task', results.task); // print the task JSON results
})
.then(initDomEvents)
.then(initTaskModalLibraries)
.finally(function(){
  console.log('finally() function ran on success and failure.... It is always ran!');
})
.catch(function(reason){
  console.log('[ERROR] REASON:',reason); //if any of the promises fails.
});
```

---

**UPDATE 2**

I see now in my new non-ajax functions I am missing `new RSVP.Promise(function(resolve, reject){})`

Fixed demo http://jsfiddle.net/jasondavis/fttzoggj/8/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your [ERROR] log line, remove `.statusText` like so:

```
.catch(function(reason){
  console.log('[ERROR] REASON:',reason); //if any of the promises fails.
});
```

you'll see this clickable error:

```
[ERROR] REASON:
ReferenceError: resolve is not defined       initDomEvents()/_display/ (line 92)
G()                                          rsvp.min.js (line 2)
F()                                          rsvp.min.js (line 2)
L()                                          rsvp.min.js (line 2)
h()                                          rsvp.min.js (line 2)
```

Here's an [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fttzoggj/7/) that I think does what you intended. The main changes are:

```
return new RSVP.Promise(initDomEvents)
```

inside your first `then` handler, which passes the returned result to the next `then` (chaining),

and change the method signature of `initDomEvents`:

```
function initDomEvents(resolve, reject) {
```

so that resolve/reject are defined.

Comment: Do you know how I can fix the error while keeping this functionality I am after?  I also added a 3rd Promise call here http://jsfiddle.net/jasondavis/fttzoggj/6/ in which the rd one is not called after the 2nd one errors

Comment: I see why now...in the new functions I am missing `new RSVP.Promise(function(resolve, reject){})`

Comment: Yes indeed! Btw, just in case, my fiddle (7) is based on your original (3).

Comment: Thanks.  As you updated your answer I came up with this version which seems to work as well http://jsfiddle.net/jasondavis/fttzoggj/8/ could you look at it an tell me if this version would be valid as well?

Comment: You're welcome. And yes, it is functionally equivalent as far as I can tell.